# How can I tell Makemaker to run tests in parallel?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, makemaker

I have a module with a MakeMaker generated Makefile and I want to run my unit tests (`make test`) in parallel. [Test::Harness](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test::Harness#HARNESS_OPTIONS) accepts e.g., `HARNESS_OPTIONS=j4` to use 4 threads. But I don't see how [MakeMaker's test](https://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#make-test) target can be adjusted to set this variable.

Now I could just export `HARNESS_OPTIONS=j4` in my `~/.bashrc` but it seems odd to force that on every test run that uses Test::Harness. What if I have tests that shouldn't run in parallel in another project?

With `make -j4 test` I don't see any improvement. `make test` runs

```
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/*/*.t
```

so I guess that even if `make` would use multiple threads, Test::Harness  may not support this, or `make` may not pass this information to Test::Harness.

Currently this just to speed up my testing. My module is an internal module and I'm not too worried about forcing this option on any user of the module. However, if I can define this option in e.g., a config file that I don't ship, that would work, too.

Speaking of config files: I can run `prove -j4 t/` and run tests in parallel. So an option could be to tell MakeMaker to run tests with `prove`, but I don't see a way to configure that either.

How can I tell MakeMaker to run this project's tests in parallel?

Comment: Can you clarify something? Do you want *users* of your module to be running tests in parallel, or is this just yor preference for your own testing locally?

Answer (score 2):

Having looked through MakeMaker's code, there doesn't seem to be a way of telling MakeMaker explicitly to (always) run tests in parallel. It just outputs the line mentioned in the question to the makefile, with the only configurable things being verbose, and the test file(s) to run.

However, if you're just wanting to set an environment variable for a single test run, then `HARNESS_OPTIONS` works fine for this purpose, just set it in your terminal before running

```
export HARNESS_OPTIONS=j4
make test
```

which will make the option persist for that terminal session, or for just a single command, `make HARNESS_OPTIONS=j4 test` will work as a oneliner.

(I originally found this question while looking for the same thing myself, but overlooked `HARNESS_OPTIONS` in the question, so I'll leave this here as a reference to others: https://perldoc.perl.org/Test::Harness#HARNESS_OPTIONS )